# Compiling and executing simple user defined code in Python

Tags: python

I want to allow my users a way to run very simple Python functions for a project. Of course, `eval()` comes to mind, but it is a huge risk. After thinking about it for a time, I realized that most of the functions that a user might need are very rudimentary, similar to the most common excel functions. So I was thinking something along the lines of maintaining a dictionary where the keys are the functions names, and the user can only pick functions which are defined (by me) within that dictionary. So for example:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

def sum(numbers):
    result = 0
    for number in numbers:
        result += number
    return number

...

function_map = {
    'add': add,
    'sum': sum,
    ...
}
```

Now, if a user defines a line as `add(4, 5)`, the result is the expected 9, however, if they define something like `foo(4)`, since the key does not exist in my dictionary, an error would be raised. My question is this: how safe is this? Are there any potential vulnerabilities that I am overlooking here?

Comment: Consider https://github.com/danthedeckie/simpleeval or perhaps the recent fork https://github.com/readevalprint/sneklang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can de-fang `eval` *somewhat* by using appropriate `globals` and `locals` arguments. For example, this is wat I used in [a kind of calculator](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/texcalc/blob/master/texcalc.py).

```
# To make eval() less dangerous by removing access
# to built-in functions.
_globals = {"__builtins__": None}
# But make standard math functions available.
_lnames = (
    'acos', 'asin', 'atan', 'ceil', 'cos', 'cosh', 'e', 'log',
    'log10', 'pi', 'sin', 'sinh', 'sqrt', 'tan', 'tanh', 'radians'
)
_locals = {k: eval('math.' + k) for k in _lnames}

value = eval(expr, _globals, _locals)
```

But you schould probably screen expressions beforehand as well. Reject those that contain `import` or `eval` or `exec`:

```
if any(j in expr for j in ('import', 'exec', 'eval')):
    raise ValueError('import, exec and eval are not allowed')
```

The module linked above also contains the use of `ast` to convert Python calculations into LaTeX math expressions. You could also use `ast` to build a custom expression evaluator.

Otherwise, here is a small stack-based [postfix expression evaluator](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/misc/blob/master/postfix.py) that I made.

One difference is that I added the number of arguments that each operator needs to the `_ops` values, so that I know how many operands to take from the stack.

```
import operator
import math

# Global constants {{{1
_add, _sub, _mul = operator.add, operator.sub, operator.mul
_truediv, _pow, _sqrt = operator.truediv, operator.pow, math.sqrt
_sin, _cos, _tan, _radians = math.sin, math.cos, math.tan, math.radians
_asin, _acos, _atan = math.asin, math.acos, math.atan
_degrees, _log, _log10 = math.degrees, math.log, math.log10
_e, _pi = math.e, math.pi
_ops = {
    '+': (2, _add),
    '-': (2, _sub),
    '*': (2, _mul),
    '/': (2, _truediv),
    '**': (2, _pow),
    'sin': (1, _sin),
    'cos': (1, _cos),
    'tan': (1, _tan),
    'asin': (1, _asin),
    'acos': (1, _acos),
    'atan': (1, _atan),
    'sqrt': (1, _sqrt),
    'rad': (1, _radians),
    'deg': (1, _degrees),
    'ln': (1, _log),
    'log': (1, _log10)
}
_okeys = tuple(_ops.keys())
_consts = {'e': _e, 'pi': _pi}
_ckeys = tuple(_consts.keys())


def postfix(expression):  # {{{1
    """
    Evaluate a postfix expression.

    Arguments:
        expression: The expression to evaluate. Should be a string or a
                    sequence of strings. In a string numbers and operators
                    should be separated by whitespace

    Returns:
        The result of the expression.
    """
    if isinstance(expression, str):
        expression = expression.split()
    stack = []
    for val in expression:
        if val in _okeys:
            n, op = _ops[val]
            if n > len(stack):
                raise ValueError('not enough data on the stack')
            args = stack[-n:]
            stack[-n:] = [op(*args)]
        elif val in _ckeys:
            stack.append(_consts[val])
        else:
            stack.append(float(val))
    return stack[-1]
```